# Invoke and return a function

Tags: javascript, function

Is there a way to do this in JS

```
function namedFunction(elements,args) {
  const domElements = document.querySelector(elements); 
  const initialValue = 0;
  let incrementBy = 5; 

  return function() {
    // Do something to domElements based on initialValue and incrementBy
    // function needs to run the first time namedFunction is called
    // and this is the only function that needs to run on subsequent calls to namedFunction
   }.call(null)
   // the .call does not work as intended here, but this is basically what I want to do.
}
```

I think I can do namedFunction()() with the code above in order to invoke both, but I'm wondering if there is another way.

The longer version of the function would look like this:

```
function namedFunction(elements,args) {
  const domElements = document.querySelector(elements); 
  const initialValue = 0;
  let incrementBy = 5; 

  function namedFunctionEventHandler() {
    // Do something to domElements based on initialValue and incrementBy
    // function needs to run the first time namedFunction is called
    // and this is the only function that needs to run on subsequent calls to namedFunction
  }

  namedFunctionEventHandler(); 
  return namedFunctionEventHandler; 
}
```

The goal would be to pass a single function as an event handler, that the first time it runs it does initial calculations, caches dom elements and the more heavier stuff, then executes the logic that is abstracted in the returned function and on subsequent calls it uses the data from the closure.

Edit: the namedFunction does not need to accept any arguments, its just for demonstration purposes.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', namedFunction)
```

is what I want to be able to do.

@CertainPerformance - Sorry, I misread your answer.
If you take a look at the end result I would like to achieve, your proposition wont actually work as intended, as if I pass an invoked function as an event handler, its gonna run before an event has actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `namedFunction` into an IIFE that saves a reference to a function (initially undefined). On call, if that variable is undefined, carry out the expensive calculations and then assign to the variable; if the variable *is* defined, then simply call it.

```
const handler = (() => {
  let cheapFn;
  return () => {
    if (cheapFn) {
      cheapFn();
      return;
    }
    // expensive calculations here
    const domElements = document.querySelector(elements); 
    ...
    cheapFn = () => {
      // assign to cheapFn
    };
    cheapFn();
  };
})();
```

Demo:

```js
const handler = (() => {
  let cheapFn;
  return () => {
    if (cheapFn) {
      cheapFn();
      return;
    }
    // expensive calculations here
    console.log('expensive');
    cheapFn = () => {
      console.log('cheap');
    };
    cheapFn();
  };
})();
document.addEventListener('scroll', handler);
```

```css
body {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
body
```

Comment: I think you have an extra return statement, the 'expensive' ones does not run.

Comment: Yes it does - check your browser console (not the snippet console), or scroll up to the top of the snippet console interface. The "expensive" runs *once*, *first*, after which only the "cheap" runs.

Comment: @wdGelwix Did you check it out? That's the sort of behavior you were looking for, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that functions in JavaScript are first-class objects, and store the function state (initialized/uninitialized) in a property of the function.

The data computed during initialization can be stored in the function properties as well, please take a look at the demo:

```js
const namedFunction = function(elements,args) {
  if (!namedFunction.isInitialized) {
      console.log('Initialization: Computing initial value...');
      namedFunction.initialValue = 10 * 10;
      console.log(`Initial value: ${namedFunction.initialValue}`);
      namedFunction.isInitialized = true;
  }
  return function() {
      console.log('Running regular operation:');
      console.log(`Current value: ${--namedFunction.initialValue}`);
  }.call(null)
}

document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', namedFunction);
```

```html
<button id="demo">Run</button>
```

Comment: I was looking for something that does not involve checking a boolean value, not sure if this will have any impact on performance for repetitive handlers ( scroll, resize ) :shrug:. This also pollutes the VE of the function, and does not actually return a function. You can see that by inserting a console log after the if statement and before the return statement. Also, if you try to copy the namedFunction into a variable and invoke it, you get an error.
I really thought there was a simpler way than all of this.